# Single record persistence with ember-data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

In Ember.js with ember-data (using the 1.0pre versions) all changes to the data are saved into a defaultTransaction on the store. When the store is committed with `store.commit()` ALL changes to the data are saved back to the API (using the RESTAdapter).

I would like more control over objects being persisted. So for now, I have been getting instances of store and adapter, then calling something like `adapter.createRecord(store, type, record)` or `updateRecord` where `type` is the `App.Person` model and record is an instance of that model.

This is using internal bits of the `DS.RESTAdapter` that I don't think are meant to be used directly. While it works I'm hoping there is a better way to gain more control over persistence then `store.commit()`. The business logic and UX of my application require finer control.

Answer (score 3):

```
transaction = router.get('store').transaction();
person = transaction.createRecord(App.Person);

person.set('name', 'Thanatos');

transaction.commit();
```

watch yehuda presentation regarding this.
http://www.cloudee.com/preview/collection/4fdfec8517ee3d671800001d

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very helpful!

But it seems like a transaction would only be useful for multiple changes (as in the defaultTransaction that all changes are added to by default). With a single change, the transaction then becomes an added layer of code around something that seems like it should be straightforward. I only have a single change, a create or an update, if I want to save/persist that single change, ember should wrap my single change in a transaction for me, if ember thinks a transaction is helpful in everything.

I might be wrong. Open to discussion!